# Trouble w/ Zycom Bike Clamp

Tags: new-bicycle-assembly

I have a Zycom 1st balance bike and I’m trying to put it together with terrible instructions and common sense. Anyway the clamp that is supposed to go around the handle bars’ bar and the front wheel bar doesn’t fit around both. And then the the clamp with a lever doesn’t tighten enough around the seat bar. This was an closed box (never been open) package. How can I solve these issues?

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  Since most of us won't be familiar with the bike you're talking about, you should include photos of the parts that are causing you a problem and the relevant details from the instructions.

Comment: Also, maybe a photo of the instructions could help. It isn't actually clear what parts you're referring to with the first issue - I assume the *front wheel bar* is the fork, and there's something clamping the fork steerer tube to the handlebars, but because they're non standard parts, it's hard to figure out the issue. The *clamp with a lever* is the seatpost clamp. It looks like a quick release clamp, and it's possible you may not be tightening that correctly; see this link: https://www.bicycling.com/repair/a20043614/the-right-way-to-close-a-quick-release/

Comment: Also: are these assembly instructions on Youtube any better than what you got in the box? If this is the correct bike, can you try to use the video's terminology for the parts to let us know what is going wrong? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5L_5iyj43s&feature=emb_logo

Answer (score 5):

Assuming this is the bike you are talking about
[image]
[Zycom My 1st ZBike](https://www.zycomotion.com/my-1st-zbike.html)

According to the [assembly video on their website](https://youtu.be/F5L_5iyj43s) (I couldn't find a manual)
The fork and handlebars are held together with a clamp
[image]

And the seat post is held into the frame with a clamp
[image]

The two clamps look similar but might be slightly different sizes. Swap them back and forth to make sure you have the right one in the right place. If one clamp is a little larger than the other the larger one could be for the fork/handlebars leaving the smaller one for the seat post clamp.

Comment: On the Walmart page for this bike (or a similar one), it looks like the seatpost clamp may be a quick release version. The link's too long to post, but if there's a quick release lever on the seatpost clamp, that should be a clear sign that it's meant to go on the seat tube, not the front end of the bike.